# Is it okay to dynamically create a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a aweber-like list management system (for phone numbers, not emails).

There are campaigns. A phone number is associated with each campaign. Users can text to a number after which they will be subscribed.

I'm building "Create a New Campaign" page.

1. My current strategy is to create a separate table for each campaign (campaign_1,campaign_2,...,campaign_n) and store the subscriber data in it.
2. It's also possible to just create a single table and add a `campaign_id` column to it.

Each campaign is supposed to have 5k to 25k users.

Which is a better option? #1 or #2?

Comment: Option 2; it will make queries about multiple campaigns a lot easier, it's easier to maintain (no need to create a table, generate the CRUD statements each time), and, really, you are pre-optimizing. It's not that much data! It will also make it easier for you if a user subscribes to multiple campaigns.

Comment: Definitely the second one. Option one could lead to a milion tables after few years of using - that will be totally unmaintainable and one could get a heart-attack looking at Your DB schema (I definitely would)... Also it is against normalization considering the campaigns could contain the same phone numbers - thus data.

Comment: In reality, your design will probably look something like this: `Campaign`, `User`, `UserCampaign` with `User` and `UserCampaign` being the large tables, but, really, `UserCampaign` will just be a link table (`UserId`, `CampaignId`) with perhaps a link to `CampaignPreferences` too. It's not a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 makes more sense and is widely used approach.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it really depends on the amount of campaigns you're going to have. Let's give you some pros/cons:

Pros for campaign_n:

- Faster queries
- You can have each instance run with its own code and own database

Cons for campaign_n:

- Database modifications are harder (you need to sync all tables)
- You get a lot of tables

Personally I'd go for option 2 (campaign_id field), unless you have a really good reason not to.